# Leaflet Legend fixed image? not SLD?

Tags: geoserver, wms, legend, leaflet

I have a style pulled from my GeoServer and have created a basic legend, with a fixed PNG. However I was wondering if it is possible to have this legend be pulled from the layers SLD? so that if the SLD is changed the legend will update too?

**This is the Legend code**

```
    var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

    legend.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');

        div.innerHTML +=
        '<img src="SymbolDelete.png" alt="legend" width="134" height="147">';

    return div;
    };

    legend.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of targeting a static PNG file, you could target the output of GeoServer's [GetLegendGraphic](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html#get-legend-graphic) service, which can return the legend for a given layer as a PNG file e.g.

```
legend.onAdd = function (map) {
var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');

    div.innerHTML +=
    '<img src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=topp:states" alt="legend" width="134" height="147">';

return div;
};
```

Comment: Changed topp:states to my layer and worked first time